# How to keep track of array elements that have already been printed and skip them (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I am writing a program that keeps track of the number of non-unique elements in an array and prints them along with their frequency. The problem with my current code is that it will print the repeated numbers more than once. I just want to print the non unique number and its frequency once, but I can't figure out how to do that. Here's my current logic. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
int numNonUnique = 0;
  int N = A.length;
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    {
        int count=0;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
        {
            if (A[i] == A[j])
                count++;
        }
      if(count>1)
      {
          numNonUnique = count;
          int currentNum = A[i];
          System.out.println(currentNum + " -> "+ numNonUnique);

      
      }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding them to a `hashset()` and use `contains()` and a 'if' statement` to see if that number is there: if it isn't, print it, if it is, skip it(`continue`). Helpful link: [using contains()](https://www.javacodeexamples.com/check-if-element-exists-in-java-hashset-example-contains/2747).

Comment: You need to keep track whether the character was seen previous or not

Comment: Is there another way of doing it that doesnt involve hashset(). we havent learned that in our class yet so im hesistant to use it. i feel like there's a simpler way to do this.

Comment: ok, you don't wan to use any storage?

Comment: i dont know what you mean by storage? my idea was maybe to store the repeated values in an array once they are printed once, but I can't figure out how to compare the previously printed values to the value about to be printed. keep in mind i just started learning java a month ago.

Comment: Does your array can contain `-1` negative numbers

Comment: no it doesnt as far as I know

Comment: Ok then there is your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Initialize array
int[] A = {-1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 7, -1};
int numNonUnique = 0;
//Array frequency will store frequencies of element
int [] frequency = new int [A.length];
int visited = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
  int count = 1;
  for(int j = i+1; j < A.length; j++){
    if(A[i] == A[j]){
      count++;
      //To avoid counting same element again
      frequency[j] = visited;
    }
  }
  if(frequency[i] != visited) frequency[i] = count;
}

//Displays the frequency of each element present in array
for(int i = 0; i < frequency.length; i++){
  if(frequency[i] != visited && frequency[i]>1){
    numNonUnique++;
    System.out.println(A[i] + " -> "+ frequency[i]);
  }
}

System.out.println("Non unique count :  "+ numNonUnique);
```

Comment: ok thank you so much, is there a way of doing it if -1 can be a number in the array? just curious because I want to understand the concept better.

Comment: First see the explaination, then lets figure out

Comment: so theoretically I could make -1 any number or maybe a character? its just some type of marker to keep track of places where numbers repeat?

Comment: Yes. But since we are using an array of type int `int[] A ` you can't add character, or string, we need to add any numeric num it can be `9999` or `-99`

Comment: ok thank you. hopefully when i turn in the assignment my professor doesn't use an array with the sentinel value that im using. but doing this some other way seems way too difficult.

Comment: @juchegod check now it's perfect. Don't forget to accept and upvote if you find it useful